# Inner join to check tables contain same values not working as expected

Tags: sql, duplicates, inner-join

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM own.no_preselection_1_a;
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM own.no_preselection_1;

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM own.no_preselection_1_a
  );

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM own.no_preselection_1
  );

SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM OWN.no_preselection_1 t1
INNER JOIN OWN.no_preselection_1_a t2
ON t1.number       = t2.number
AND t1.location_number = t2.location_number;
```

This returns:

```
COUNT(1)               
---------------------- 
398                    

COUNT(1)               
---------------------- 
398                    

COUNT(1)               
---------------------- 
308                    

COUNT(1)               
---------------------- 
308                    

COUNT(1)               
---------------------- 
578
```

If we look at the visual explanation of joins here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

The problem is on that last query. I would have thought that if the sets are the same (ie a perfect overlap), then the inner join would would return a set the size of the original sets.

Is the problem that each of the duplicates are creating entries for *all* of each other? (eg if there are 3 dupes of the same value on each table, it would create 3x3 = 9 entries for it?) 
What's the solution here? (Just select the distincts to do the inner join on?) Is this a good test for checking if two tables contain the same data?

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicates in your table, as the first and third, and second and fourth counts in your list make clear.

The join is working as it should, so there is no "problem".  What are you trying to accomplish?  Your goal is not being satisfied by the join.

I would suggest that you annotate your question with some actual data and the results that you want.

If you want to show that the two tables have the same values, you might try a union.  Assuming that all the columns are the same in both tables and the columns in a row uniquely identify each row:

```
select t.*
from ((select '1' as which, t.*
       from OWN.no_preselection_1 t
      ) union all
      (select '1-a' as which, t.*
       from OWN.no_preselection_1_a
      )
     ) t
group by < all the columns in the tables >
having count(*) <> 1
```

If you are limited to the two columns and want to see if there are corresponding entries (with duplicates), the following works:

```
select t.*
from ((select '1' as which, number, location_number,
              row_number() over (partition by number, location_number order by number) as seqnum
       from OWN.no_preselection_1 t
      ) union all
      (select '1-a' as which, number, location_number,
              row_number() over (partition by number, location_number order by number) as seqnum
       from OWN.no_preselection_1_a
      )
     ) t
group by number, location_number, seqnum
having count(*) <> 1
```

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve, is to show that the two tables contain the exact same values.